# Compress the file size of pdf plot in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have saved several pdf plots with large file size in R, the problem is that I will need to import them into Latex, which takes a lot of time. I am wondering how to save a plot with smaller file size in R? Thanks.

Example 1.

```
 seasonplot(ts(hdemand$Demand,frequency=24),   
           col=rainbow(length(hdemand$Demand)/48))
dev.print(device=pdf,file="hourdemand.pdf")
dev.off()
```

[image]

Example 2. (Even the fitted plot takes times because of the size of data)

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(data$Temp,all.data$Demand)
abline(lm(data$Demand~data$Temp), col="red") 

plot(data$APX,data$Demand)
abline(lm(data$Demand~data$APX), col="red") 
dev.print("LR.pdf",device=pdf)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the number of points you are plotting.

But if you can't do that, and don't care about how it would look when zoomed in, write out as png at a convenient dpi and then convert to pdf outside R.